# How to create an Achive with views

Tags: views

I want to create an archive from my news with views and filter it by post date.
How can I do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's a default view that comes with the Views module that will provide the block, it's called Archive and that'd be your best start point, enable it in `admin/structure/views` and  you'll get both the block with the items grouped by date and a page.

[image]

Find an advanced customization of this in http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/creating-monthly-archive-block-drupal-7-views

Answer (score 0):

YOu just need to add a filter of post date/created date [image]

To filter the content accorrding to the post date just tick the **Expose this filter to visitor**.
You can see it is added above the listing under your view page.

If you want  to display this form in the front end  then set "**Exposed form in block**" under Advanced tab to "**Yes**". Now go to block listing page then assign it in the desired region.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I want to insert the date filter Like 2014/06/25 and the format of "Value type" is different,How can I change the format of filter?

Comment: And another problem is that my Date format is hijri not Gregorian!

Comment: It accepts date in YYYY/MM/DD format. Just change your date to this format before passing it to view or you can user hool_query_alter function of view to change it programmatically